# Ошибка sh: line 9: 19705: Memory fault(coredump) при установке OpenSSH

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, solaris

Скачал `openssh-6.1.p1/tar.gz` с http://mirror.corbina.net/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/. Сделал сначала `./configure`, затем `make`, которые вроде бы отработали без ошибок(операционная система `Nexenta Illumos`). В результате выполнения `make install` получил следующие сообщения

```
(cd openbsd-compat && make)
./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/bin
./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/sbin
./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/share/man
./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/share/man/man1
./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/share/man/man5
./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/share/man/man8
./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/libexec
(umask 022 ; ./mkinstalldirs /var/empty)
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s ssh /usr/local/bin/ssh
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s scp /usr/local/bin/scp
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s ssh-add /usr/local/bin/ssh-add
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s ssh-agent /usr/local/bin/ssh-agent
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s ssh-keygen /usr/local/bin/ssh-keygen
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s ssh-keyscan /usr/local/bin/ssh-keyscan
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s sshd /usr/local/sbin/sshd
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 4711 -s ssh-keysign /usr/local/libexec/ssh-keysign
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s ssh-pkcs11-helper /usr/local/libexec/ssh-pkcs11-helper
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s sftp /usr/local/bin/sftp
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s sftp-server /usr/local/libexec/sftp-server
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh.1.out /usr/local/share/man/man1/ssh.1
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 scp.1.out /usr/local/share/man/man1/scp.1
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh-add.1.out /usr/local/share/man/man1/ssh-add.1
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh-agent.1.out /usr/local/share/man/man1/ssh-agent.1
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh-keygen.1.out /usr/local/share/man/man1/ssh-keygen.1
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh-keyscan.1.out /usr/local/share/man/man1/ssh-keyscan.1
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 moduli.5.out /usr/local/share/man/man5/moduli.5
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 sshd_config.5.out /usr/local/share/man/man5/sshd_config.5
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh_config.5.out /usr/local/share/man/man5/ssh_config.5
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 sshd.8.out /usr/local/share/man/man8/sshd.8
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 sftp.1.out /usr/local/share/man/man1/sftp.1
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 sftp-server.8.out /usr/local/share/man/man8/sftp-server.8
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh-keysign.8.out /usr/local/share/man/man8/ssh-keysign.8
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh-pkcs11-helper.8.out /usr/local/share/man/man8/ssh-pkcs11-helper.8
rm -f /usr/local/bin/slogin
ln -s ./ssh /usr/local/bin/slogin
rm -f /usr/local/share/man/man1/slogin.1
ln -s ./ssh.1 /usr/local/share/man/man1/slogin.1
if [ ! -d /usr/local/etc ]; then \
    ./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/etc; \
fi
/usr/local/etc/ssh_config already exists, install will not overwrite
/usr/local/etc/sshd_config already exists, install will not overwrite
/usr/local/etc/moduli already exists, install will not overwrite
/usr/local/etc/ssh_host_key already exists, skipping.
sh: line 9: 19705: Memory fault(coredump)
*** Signal 11 - core dumped
The following command caused the error:
if [ -z "" ] ; then \
    if [ -f "/usr/local/etc/ssh_host_key" ] ; then \
        echo "/usr/local/etc/ssh_host_key already exists, skipping." ; \
    else \
        ./ssh-keygen -t rsa1 -f /usr/local/etc/ssh_host_key -N "" ; \
    fi ; \
    if [ -f /usr/local/etc/ssh_host_dsa_key ] ; then \
        echo "/usr/local/etc/ssh_host_dsa_key already exists, skipping." ; \
    else \
        ./ssh-keygen -t dsa -f /usr/local/etc/ssh_host_dsa_key -N "" ; \
    fi ; \
    if [ -f /usr/local/etc/ssh_host_rsa_key ] ; then \
        echo "/usr/local/etc/ssh_host_rsa_key already exists, skipping." ; \
    else \
        ./ssh-keygen -t rsa -f /usr/local/etc/ssh_host_rsa_key -N "" ; \
    fi ; \
    if [ -z "#no ecc#" ] ; then \
        if [ -f /usr/local/etc/ssh_host_ecdsa_key ] ; then \
        echo "/usr/local/etc/ssh_host_ecdsa_key already exists, skipping." ; \
        else \
        ./ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -f /usr/local/etc/ssh_host_ecdsa_key -N "" ; \
        fi ; \
    fi ; \
fi ;
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `host-key'
```

Помогите устранить ошибку.

P.S. В результате повторного выполнения команды `make install` обнаруживаю, что происходит зависание на строке

```
fi
mkdir /usr/local/etc
```

(но вообще-то место зависания бывает разным при разных запусках, хотя на всех немногочисленных запусках, которые я проводил останавливалось на блоке

```
fi
/usr/local/etc/ssh_config already exists, install will not overwrite
/usr/local/etc/sshd_config already exists, install will not overwrite
/usr/local/etc/moduli already exists, install will not overwrite
/usr/local/etc/ssh_host_key already exists, skipping.
```

).

Comment: Я надеюсь вы под `root` выполняете `make install`,

Comment: @Gedweb естественно под `root`.

Comment: @Rules, тут больше аудитория пользователей, а вопрос очень важный (через репозиторий соответсвующий аналог не устанавливается).

Comment: А что мешает везде на форумах этот вопрос задать например на [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/ "StackOverflow")