# Установка openssh

Tags: unix, solaris, ssh, bash, linux

Этот вопрос непосредственно связан с вопросами [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/183869/linux-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-sh-line-9-19705-memory-fault-coredump-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5-openssh) и [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/184447/linux-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-gmake). После очередного выполнения команды `make install` я получил следующий лог

```
(cd openbsd-compat && make)
./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/bin
./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/sbin
./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/share/man
./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/share/man/man1
./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/share/man/man5
./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/share/man/man8
./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/libexec
(umask 022 ; ./mkinstalldirs /var/empty)
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s ssh /usr/local/bin/ssh
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s scp /usr/local/bin/scp
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s ssh-add /usr/local/bin/ssh-add
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s ssh-agent /usr/local/bin/ssh-agent
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s ssh-keygen /usr/local/bin/ssh-keygen
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s ssh-keyscan /usr/local/bin/ssh-keyscan
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s sshd /usr/local/sbin/sshd
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 4711 -s ssh-keysign /usr/local/libexec/ssh-keysign
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s ssh-pkcs11-helper /usr/local/libexec/ssh-pkcs11-helper
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s sftp /usr/local/bin/sftp
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s sftp-server /usr/local/libexec/sftp-server
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh.1.out /usr/local/share/man/man1/ssh.1
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 scp.1.out /usr/local/share/man/man1/scp.1
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh-add.1.out /usr/local/share/man/man1/ssh-add.1
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh-agent.1.out /usr/local/share/man/man1/ssh-agent.1
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh-keygen.1.out /usr/local/share/man/man1/ssh-keygen.1
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh-keyscan.1.out /usr/local/share/man/man1/ssh-keyscan.1
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 moduli.5.out /usr/local/share/man/man5/moduli.5
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 sshd_config.5.out /usr/local/share/man/man5/sshd_config.5
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh_config.5.out /usr/local/share/man/man5/ssh_config.5
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 sshd.8.out /usr/local/share/man/man8/sshd.8
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 sftp.1.out /usr/local/share/man/man1/sftp.1
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 sftp-server.8.out /usr/local/share/man/man8/sftp-server.8
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh-keysign.8.out /usr/local/share/man/man8/ssh-keysign.8
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh-pkcs11-helper.8.out /usr/local/share/man/man8/ssh-pkcs11-helper.8
rm -f /usr/local/bin/slogin
ln -s ./ssh /usr/local/bin/slogin
rm -f /usr/local/share/man/man1/slogin.1
ln -s ./ssh.1 /usr/local/share/man/man1/slogin.1
if [ ! -d /usr/local/etc ]; then \
    ./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/etc; \
fi
/usr/local/etc/ssh_config already exists, install will not overwrite
/usr/local/etc/sshd_config already exists, install will not overwrite
/usr/local/etc/moduli already exists, install will not overwrite
/usr/local/etc/ssh_host_key already exists, skipping.
/usr/local/etc/ssh_host_dsa_key already exists, skipping.
/usr/local/etc/ssh_host_rsa_key already exists, skipping.
/usr/local/sbin/sshd -t -f /usr/local/etc/sshd_config
Privilege separation user sshd does not exist
*** Error code 255 (ignored)
```

Comment: на будущее: не нужно вываливать лог всей операции в пост, достаточно последних 5-10 строк

Answer (score 1):

здесь запускается `sshd` для тестирования указанного конфигурационного файла:

```
/usr/local/sbin/sshd -t -f /usr/local/etc/sshd_config
Privilege separation user sshd does not exist
```

программа сообщает об ошибке: согласно конфигурации (возможно, по дефолту), требуется «разделение привилегий» (опция `UsePrivilegeSeparation yes`), т.е. запуск дочерних процессов, выполняющих «реальную работу» от имени непривилегированного пользователя `sshd`.

возможные выходы:

1. создать предварительно этого пользователя (команда `useradd sshd`).
2. указать — **не** использовать «разделение привилегий» (опция `UsePrivilegeSeparation no` в указанном конфигурационном файле).